# is there any way to save data locally when app closed

Tags: flutter, sqlite

the app works with sqlite database and it shows the data that exits in the assets very fine even though when the app closed those data is still there , the problem is when connecting with server and loading data it is saved and displayed in the app very fine but only when the app running , if the app closed every thing lost and I just found the data that already exists in assets from the beginning .
how I can save the data that loading from the server in local database even if the app is closed?

here is my database initialize function

```
Future<Database> initDb() async {
if (kIsWeb) {
  try {

  } catch (_) {}
  // Set web-specific directory Here
} else {
  Directory documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  String path = join(documentDirectory.path, "data_4us.db");

  // Load database from asset and copy
  ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(join('data', '4us.db'));
  List<int> bytes =
  data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);

  // Save copied asset to documents
  await new File(path).writeAsBytes(bytes);

  var ourDb = await openDatabase(path);
  return ourDb;
} }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, I think I solve the problem
I just add this if statement to check the existing of the database

```
if (FileSystemEntity.typeSync(path) == FileSystemEntityType.notFound){ }
```

now everything is fine.
thank you .